# Retrive data from MongoDB using mongoose and generate CSV/XLSX file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, express, xlsx

Is there any npm module to retrive data from mongodb using mongoose and generate csv or xlsx file?
How do i generate csv or xlsx file using node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CSV-Transform](https://www.npmjs.org/package/csv-transform) is something might help to convert mongodb cursor data(data from query result) to csv file.

It also have example available for How To Use it.

Hope it helps..!!!